# How to split a stand in packets per class and per unit in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a problem in my e-commerce, need to share certain class of products in a new package in my cart, but if you buy more than one unit of that class each unit is separated into a separate package.

For example:

A customer buys the following products:

Qty. Description

1 | Jacket Bear (product class - normal);

1 | Lustre Pearl (product class - normal);

2 | Trousseau theme Aviator (product class - grande);

Where do I enter the code below to split the cart for the "grande" class:

```html
function split_special_shipping_class_items( $packages ) {
 $found_item                     = false;
 $special_class                  = 'grande'; // edit this with the slug of your shippig class
 $new_package                    = current( $packages );
 $new_package['contents']        = array();
 $new_package['contents_cost']   = 0;
 $new_package['applied_coupons'] = array();
 $new_package['ship_via']        = array(); // Only allow flat rate for items in special class
 
 foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
  // Is the product in the special class?
  if ( $item['data']->needs_shipping() && $special_class === $item['data']->get_shipping_class() ) {
   $found_item                            = true;
   $new_package['contents'][ $item_key ]  = $item;
   $new_package['contents_cost']         += $item['line_total'];

   // Remove from original package
   $packages[0]['contents_cost'] = $packages[0]['contents_cost'] - $item['line_total'];
   unset( $packages[0]['contents'][ $item_key ] );

   // If there are no items left in the previous package, remove it completely.
   if ( empty( $packages[0]['contents'] ) ) {
    unset( $packages[0] );
   }
  }
 }
 if ( $found_item ) {
    $packages[] = $new_package;
 }
 return $packages;
}

// Hook into shipping packages filter
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'split_special_shipping_class_items' );
```

The result is:
[image]

But what I need is that besides split the cart as the "grande" class, the product has the class "grande" and contain more than one unit, it is divided 1 per package, as showing in the image below:

[image]

Would it be possible?

Tks!